# How to filter/search/highlight columns in HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html

How to filter/search/highlight columns in HTML table?
I have a problem when highlighting the matches that my search engine finds, the problem is that when deleting some characters they remain marked, could someone help me and explain why that happens, I have an example in which it is done by column and it works fine for me the problem now is that I want to perform the search by row and highlight the matches.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        // td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        alltags = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        isFound = false;
        tr[i].style.display = "";
        for(j=0; j< alltags.length; j++) {
          td = alltags[j];
          if (td) {
              txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
              index = txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter);
              if (index > -1) {
                 td.innerHTML = txtValue.substring(-1, index) + "<mark>" + txtValue.substring(index, index + filter.length) + "</mark>" + txtValue.substring(index + filter.length);
                  tr[j].style.display = "";
                  j = alltags.length;
                  isFound = true;
              }
            }       
          }
          if(!isFound && tr[i].className !== "header") {
            // tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

    <table id="myTable">
        <tr class="header">
            <th> First Name </th>
            <th> Last Name </th> 
            <th> Age </th>
            <th> Language </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Kole</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>English</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pearl</td>
            <td>Shine</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>Hindi</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Pool</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>Arabic</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
            <td>David</td>
            <td>Struff</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>German</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: It looks like the function searches every `<td>` in the `<table>` and isn't restricted by column or row -- try searching for "d". Usually column and rows are targeted when sorting is involved.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem when the value in the search box is empty string, you don't remove the final highlighted letter of the previous search. I added an `else` statement to your code as well as a check for empty string in the search term before adding a `mark` tag and it works as intended.

```js
function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            // td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            alltags = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            isFound = false;
            tr[i].style.display = "";
            for(j=0; j< alltags.length; j++) {
              td = alltags[j];
              if (td) {
                  txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                  index = txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter);
                  if (index > -1 && filter !== "") {
                     td.innerHTML = txtValue.substring(-1, index) + "<mark>" + txtValue.substring(index, index + filter.length) + "</mark>" + txtValue.substring(index + filter.length);
                      tr[j].style.display = "";
                      j = alltags.length;
                      isFound = true;
                  } else {
                      td.innerHTML = td.textContent;
                  }
                }       
              }
              if(!isFound && tr[i].className !== "header") {
                // tr[i].style.display = "none";
              }
            }
        }
```

```html
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

        <table id="myTable">
            <tr class="header">
                <th> First Name </th>
                <th> Last Name </th> 
                <th> Age </th>
                <th> Language </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Kole</td>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>English</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Pearl</td>
                <td>Shine</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Hindi</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Pool</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>Arabic</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>David</td>
                <td>Struff</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>German</td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution is to remove the mark from the TD's innerHTML before doing a search in that TD. That way it will always show the current results.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        // td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        alltags = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        isFound = false;
        tr[i].style.display = "";
        for(j=0; j< alltags.length; j++) {
          td = alltags[j];
          if (td) {
              td.innerHTML = td.innerHTML.replaceAll("<mark>","");
              td.innerHTML = td.innerHTML.replaceAll("</mark>","");
              txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
              index = txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter);
              if (index > -1) {
                 td.innerHTML = txtValue.substring(-1, index) + "<mark>" + txtValue.substring(index, index + filter.length) + "</mark>" + txtValue.substring(index + filter.length);
                  tr[j].style.display = "";
                  j = alltags.length;
                  isFound = true;
              }
            }       
          }
          if(!isFound && tr[i].className !== "header") {
            // tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

    <table id="myTable">
        <tr class="header">
            <th> First Name </th>
            <th> Last Name </th> 
            <th> Age </th>
            <th> Language </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Kole</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>English</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pearl</td>
            <td>Shine</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>Hindi</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Pool</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>Arabic</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
            <td>David</td>
            <td>Struff</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>German</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```